# firefox sound not available

Tags: firefox

I was using [Oxford online dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/happy). When I clicked the prunuciation button, a message popped up saying "Apologies, the sound is not available."

Here is a screenshot. [image: the popup message]
larger image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXGF.png

I have tested this on another browser (Chromium) and did not have this problem.

How do I get it to play in Firefox?

Comment: See this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues

Comment: I have followed through [the instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues), but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Can you send the page source?(use pastebin)

Comment: Sure,here is the [page source](http://pastebin.com/5LmTXEQG)

Comment: Does any other sound work in your browser? Try this http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/media/english/uk_pron/h/hap/happy/happy__gb_1.mp3 and http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/media/english/us_pron/h/hap/happy/happy__us_1.mp3

Comment: It says "Video can't be played because the file is corrupt" for both links. I have also cleared the cache and cookies, but the result is the same. Here are the screenshots [screenshot1](https://i.imgur.com/CAK8Vaz.png) and [screenshot2](https://i.imgur.com/aAPwFLn.png)

Answer (score 1):

short answer:

step 1) open Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T

step 2) type

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

step 3) restart Firefox

---

my problem solving process:

I accidentally solved my own problem. What I need is an MP3 codec. I DOWNLOADed the [pronunciation files](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/media/english/uk_pron/h/hap/happy/happy__gb_1.mp3)(links were provided by "saptarshi nag") and double-clicked to play it with Rhythmbox, but Rhythmbox told me to install a codec "gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly". Restart Firefox after the codec was installed, and it's done. I can now play the pronunciations successfully.

Comment: Oh so you did not have gstreamer then.

Comment: Thank you very very much.. :) It completely solve the problem.. :)